# Adding a custom sparse op (Sparse Determinant)

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am working on trying to get some sparse matrix operations working in Tensorflow. The first one I am tackling is a sparse determinant, via a sparse Cholesky decomposition. Eigen has a sparse Cholesky, so my thought is to wrap that.

I have been making some progress, but am now a little bit stuck. I know that SparseTensors in Tensorflow are made up of three parts: `indices`, `values`, and `shape`. Copying similar ops, I went for the following `REGISTER_OP` declaration:

```
REGISTER_OP("SparseLogDet")
    .Input("a_indices: int64")
    .Input("a_values: float32")
    .Input("a_shape: int64")
    .Output("determinant: float32")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
      shape_inference::ShapeHandle h;
      c->set_output(0, h);
      return Status::OK();
    });
```

This compiles fine, but when I run it using some example code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

log_det_op = tf.load_op_library('./sparse_log_det_op.so')

with tf.Session(''):
  t = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0], [1, 2]], values=[1, 2],
                      dense_shape=[3, 4])
  print(log_det_op.sparse_log_det(t).eval().shape)
  print(log_det_op.sparse_log_det(t).eval())
```

It complains, saying:

`TypeError: sparse_log_det() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a_values' and 'a_shape'`

This makes sense to me, since it's expecting the other arguments. However, I would really just like to pass the sparse tensor, not break it up into components! Does anyone know how this is handled for other sparse operations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass in the sparse tensor and then determine `indices`, `values` and `shape` from this, this should be possible. Just modify your OP to take a single `Tensor` input, and produce a single `float` output. Then extract the desired information form the Eigen::Tensor by looping through its elements as seen below:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace tensorflow;

REGISTER_OP("SparseDeterminant")
    .Input("sparse_tensor: float")
    .Output("sparse_determinant: float");


class SparseDeterminantOp : public OpKernel {
public:
    explicit SparseDeterminantOp(OpKernelConstruction *context) : OpKernel(context) {}

    void Compute(OpKernelContext *context) override {

   // get the input tesnorflow tensor
   const Tensor& sparse_tensor = context->input(0);  
   // get shape of input
   const TensorShape& sparse_shape = sparse_tensor.shape();

   // get Eigen Tensor for input tensor
   auto eigen_sparse = sparse_tensor.matrix<float>();

   //extract the data you want from the sparse tensor input
   auto a_shape = sparse_tensor.shape();

   // loop over all elements of the input tensor and add to values and indices
   for (int i=0; i<a_shape.dim_size(0); ++i){
    for (int j=0; j<a_shape.dim_size(1); ++j){
        if(eigen_sparse(i,j) != 0){
        /// ***Here add non zero elements to list/tensor of values and their indicies*** 
            std::cout<<eigen_sparse(i,j)<<" at"<<" "<<i<<" "<<j<<" "<<"not zero."<<std::endl;
        }
    }
   }

   // create output tensor
   Tensor *output_tensor = NULL;      
   TensorShape output_shape;
   OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, output_shape, &output_tensor));
   auto output = output_tensor->scalar<float>();

   output(0) = 1.; //**asign return value***;

    }
};
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("SparseDeterminant").Device(DEVICE_CPU), SparseDeterminantOp);
```

sadly, when you pass `t` into your op it becomes a `Tensorflow::Tensor` and loses the `values` and `indices` methods associated with `tf.sparsetensor`, so you can't get them easily.

Once compiled this code can be run with:

```
//run.py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

my_module = tf.load_op_library('./out.so')

# create sparse matrix
a = np.zeros((10,10))
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i,i] = i

print(a)

a_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(a, dtype= float)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(my_module.sparse_determinant(a_t))
```